# How to have CVS files in different directory than source files in NetBeans?

Tags: php, netbeans, cvs, netbeans6.8

I have a project in NetBeans which haven't used CVS until now. Let's say the directory with source files is called `/www/source_files` and directory with project files `/www/project_files`. Module in repository is called differently than source files directory. When I'm trying to check out CVS, it forces me to create a directory called exactly how module is called, which is fine by me in fact. Straight after it asks me if I wanted to create new project. And here the problem begins. I don't want to do that and I have no idea how to link newly created directory with CVS and checked out files with my project.

I'd like to end up with following structure:

```
/www
    /source_files
    /project_files
    /cvs_files
```

Any ideas how to do this? I'm using NetBeans 6.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm going to answer my own question here. I found something different, but it basically does the same as I wanted.

I checked out CVS module into `/www/source_cvs`, as I did before. Then it asked me once again if I wanted to create new project. This time I said yes and made a project **in checked out directory**. But I also checked "Copy files from Sources Folder to another location" and set it to `/www/source_files`.

So in the end, I'm working all the time in directory which has CVS files in it, but it always copies whole content of this directory to another clean one.